# Proof using set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the function :  →  and the statement

(,):∀, ∈ (), ^−1 = ( ∩ ^)= ^−1() ∩ [^−1()]^c

where () is the power set of set.

(,) ∧ (, ) ≡ ∀,  ∈ (), ^-1 (C-D) = f^-1(c) - [f^-1(D)]^c

You must use the set-element method of proof to prove that (,) is true. In your proof you must consider all possible subset relationships between  and , including cases
of empty sets.

I cannot figure out what sets I start out with and why it says (,) ∧ (, ). Do I use C and D^c or A and B (if it is the latter I don't quite understand how the proof would be done)? Also how would I define all the cases (I generally know what they are but would I write for example case 1: x is an element of C intersect D^c, C and D^c are not the empty set) ?

For the first case, I am considering where x is an element of the intersection of C and D^c.  Can I assume that if x is in this intersection then x is also in f^-1(C ∩ D^c), and then that by definition of f^-1, x is also in ^−1() ∩ [^−1()]^c ? From there the set difference law would get us to f^-1(c) - [f^-1(D)]^c, but I don't know if this is a correct proof or if I'm actually answering what the question is asking.

Thanks

Comment: Most of the variables show as empty rectangles making your question unreadable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean because on my laptop it is showing up fine.